# Any vulnerability of OCSP for proof of concept

Tags: certificates, known-vulnerabilities, protocols, certificate-revocation, ocsp

I have an assignment in which I have to implement OCSP and do a proof of concept of a vulnerability.

My idea was to implement OCSP without using a nonce (this is done) and then perform a replay attack. However I'm having trouble doing the replay attack on localhost.

Does anyone have another suggestion for a proof of concept of an attack I can do? I can't find much about this.

Comment: *"proof of concept of a vulnerability"* - vulnerability in what? In the server side generation of OCSP response, in the client side validation, ... . A classic problem is that clients do a fail-open when OCSP server does not respond in time, i.e. they treat the certificate as valid even if it was already revoked.